# Is it possible to overwrite the action-value in a form?

Tags: html, forms

is it possible to overwrite the action-value of one searchfield when submitting the value of the second searchfield?
I'm in need of adding a searchfield

```
      <input type="search" id="id2">
      <input type="submit" value="value2" />
```

to:

```
  <form method="get" action="/../.." id="search">
    <div>
      <input type="search" id="id1">
      <input type="submit" value="value1" />
  </div>
  </form>
```

By pressing enter in the second searchfield, I'm forwarded to the link of the first searchfield because it has an action-value.

Can I change this behaviour?

Comment: You means when you click on value2... You want the action parameter of form set to the value that is in id2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript :

```
    function setAction(){ 
        document.getElementById('search').setAttribute('action',document.getElementById('id2').value
    }
```

You need to set onClick event of 'id2' with setAction().